# Return true if list contains a sequence of numbers

Tags: python, loops

I have been stuck on this question for a while as my code keeps failing. So the question is to find whether a sequence e.g. 1, 2, 3 occurs in a certain list. I have written it like this:

```
def has123(nums): 
    """"Takes a list of one or more ints nums and returns True if 
    the sequence 1, 3, 5 appears in the list somewhere and false 
    otherwise"""   
    for i in range(len(nums)-1): 
        if nums[i] == 1: 
            if nums[i+1] == 2: 
                if nums[+2] == 3: 
                    return True
    return False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: well to start with +2 should be i+2, additionally you should only check the range up to len(nums) - 3 (since 3 is the length of your target subsequence)

Comment: When `i` gets near the end of the list, `i+1` and `i+2` will be out of bounds.

Comment: `my code keeps failing` It would help if you explained how it is failing.  Does the code raise an exception?  Does it give the wrong answer?  Does it give no answer at all?

Comment: Please make up your mind about whether you want 1,2,3 or 1,3,5...

Comment: Please be more descriptive in your question on how its failing.

Answer (score 3):

As usual, it's simpler and safer to not use indexes.

```
def has123(nums): 
    """"Takes a list of one or more ints nums and returns True if 
    the sequence 1, 3, 5 appears in the list somewhere and false 
    otherwise"""
    return (1, 3, 5) in zip(nums, nums[1:], nums[2:])
```

(Note 1: Oh well ok, I'm using indexes for the slices as well, but those are trivial :-)

(Note 2: I changed the values to 1,3,5 because that's what the docstring says, waiting for OP to decide what they really want)

Answer (score 1):

```
def has123(nums):
    """"Takes a list of one or more ints nums and returns True if
    the sequence 1, 3, 5 appears in the list somewhere and false
    otherwise"""
    # only go to len(nums) - 2
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):
        if nums[i] == 1:
            if nums[i+1] == 2:
                # check  i+2 (not +2)
                if nums[i+2] == 3:
                    return True
    return False


print(has123([4,5,1,2,3,7])) # True
print(has123([4,5,1,2,2,7])) # False
```

Comment: Like I say in mine, simpler and safer to not even try :-P

Comment: I agree :P i was just trying to modify OP code as little as I could :p

Comment: Hi, 

What exactly does the -2 next to len(list) do?

Comment: if len(x) = 3, then len(x)-2 = 1 and statement is `for item in range(1)` which will check the 0th item only ... if len(x) is 4 then it would be 2 and check the first 2 elements so s[i+1] and s[i+2] both exist for sure

Answer (score 1):

```
def has123(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums) - 2):
        if nums[i:i + 3] == [1, 3, 5]:
            return True
    return False
```

### Option 2

solution with variable pattern length

```
def has123(nums:list, pattern:list):
    sz = len(pattern)
    for i in range(len(nums) - sz + 1):
        if nums[i:i + sz] == pattern:
            return True
    return False
 
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

print(has123(lst,[1,2,3]))      #True
print(has123(lst,[5,6,7,8]))    #True
print(has123(lst,[1,2,4]))      #False
print(has123(lst,[1,3,2]))      #False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def has123(nums):
    """"Takes a list of one or more ints nums and returns True if
    the sequence 1, 3, 5 appears in the list somewhere and false
    otherwise"""
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):
        if nums[i] == 1 and nums[i+1] == 2 and nums[i+2] == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid too much indexing and creation of intermediate structures, you can use enumerate() to obtain a value and an index as an iterator.  Using any() on the iterator will stop the process as soon as one sequence is found.  You can check the other two  indexes (preceding in my example) when the value matches the corresponding position in your search sequence (1,2,3):

```
def hasSeqOf3(nums,a=1,b=2,c=3):
    return any(nums[i]==a and nums[i+1]==b for i,n in enumerate(nums,-2)
               if n==c and i>=0))
```

This ensures that checking for '3' incurs no indexing penalty. Indexing will only be used when a '3' is actually found. This should be more efficient than looping on indexes for all 3 value checks.

Comment: Creating the tuples doesn't appear to make it slower. [Demo](https://tio.run/##fVHbToQwEH3nK@Zls61WQ@FFSWris4k/YDakwKBNYCDdbuL689gLazBe5oHSmTPnnM7MZ/c2UXk322Xp7TSCMyMaB2acJ@vA4ozaZVmHPTwO2hCj03gUWknRqEK0quRVBj4supMl0HSOiBdzUEr7awfpei19ooF@smAEgSFAX0CrHSbKm4JHok2YHkipNrKYB5Xz5OMJhyGqfLcBWx9Mi0a0POh8mDkpJCeyOqx/RXXYMhY/KSOjcQUo/0UbAMkk4btjviDgeSLkK678C1ducb/l/nMdZTzeew0JrzGYo2NW0ysymYfgPAuDrUNjyl/Mh3R/ojZU4v5Eeux6FNXXzJ0nHv1@08bZoMem01VsXo3kAqSAksfxNWiVDMKX/tkacmy/k3m3hx0wB1cg8d6jA8VtXZMesa5TQwLzZfkE)

Comment: In my tests it's about 50% slower on a list of 4000 numbers where the sequence is in the middle (or not in the list at all).  I was comparing to `any(abc==(1,2,3) for abc in zip(nums,nums[1:],nums[2:]))`.  Using `tuple in ...` is clearly more efficient than what I had, and is marginally faster than the enumerate comprehension.

Comment: Well, that somewhat looks like you were trying to make that almost as slow as possible :-P. At least you used the constant `(1,2,3)` instead of `(a,b,c)`, which would've been built over and over again. The `tuple in zip` way has several advantages, even lets `zip` reuse/refill its result tuple. With marginally faster, do you mean my Kelly function or my Kelly2 variant, or some other?

Comment: My previous benchmark was very friendly for your solution, in a [very unfriendly](https://tio.run/##fVHLToUwEN3zFbO5ua1WQ2GjJDVxbeIP3BBSYNAmtJBaEq8/j32gYnzMorQzZ845zMxn9zyZ8ma26zrYSYNTGpUDpefJOrA4o3RZ1uMA96NUhphFvzApOGtFwTpR0ioDHxbdYg1Ic46Ik6qFkP7ZQ3pecp9oYZgsKGZAGUBfQCsdJsqrgkaiXagBjBBdZFF3IqfJxwOOY1T5bgP2PohkLeto0HlTc1JITnhVb7eiqveMxU/KyKhcAcKfaAMgmTT46ogvMHicDNINV/6FK/e433L/uY4yHu@9hoTXOOU1XADPQ2Rhok3osNI8IflwHdLDYrpQiYtj6S@3T1F9Dtt5Ru0Xm1ZNRqnbXlaxeXOQM@D@pHFuLVrBc/q1rNkq48jxwPP@CAcgLnjDW48OFNdNY6TGpkkNCUzX9R0) one (searching 010 in 000000...) it takes ~5 times as long as my optimized one.

Comment: One more: [optimized yours as well](https://tio.run/##vZPBToQwEIbvPMVcNgtaDZSLktTEs4knbxtCCjvoJFBILYnry2NbUNkIiV7sAeh0@s83f2l/Mi@dSm96PY617low1CIZoLbvtAGNPUoTBEes4b6RpEI1tK9MioSVgrNKpFEWgB0azaAVSHXyGQfKhZB2eoRpepnYQAl1p4GYAlKAdgG1NDhJXvHICy0G1aCEqLwK3Yk4WnDwLRDLLra0Fb6ZkAyDx07hZujvrZDZQF8Sp/9C/KQH/BXaoqHV/mb0B2wa78M5OCzrhpKVrIpcuXfqpwYmrSTL5y@e5UtF/lNy9oJbM8igdglnDfNlx2TSrbx0xax0xa1Val/G5ltWF7A1DnEOF5DEbgTO2MLt0FI9Y/hJ7cL1oCq34s@azT/p/Lblfdfzi2dfZ@KOvrW3arpnYSPb8igzLzYTxQwS@4y8jyVqkcTR903pNSkT7ndJfNzDDkLjWPHWZjuJ66JQssWimDZMydE4fgA). You might actually want to use that second optimization.

Comment: That 010 pattern in a series of zeroes is nasty :).  It nicely highlights how much my enumeration approach is data dependent and can be much slower than a tuple searched in an iterator at the C-code level.